# Django - Clone model object in Class based ListView

Tags: django, model, clone, django-class-based-views

I have a `list.html` with lots of records and a column containing a button to clone the specific record like this:

```
{% for betr in object_list %}
    ....
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-first" onclick="window.location='../clone/{{betr.ID}}';">
            <span class="fas fa-copy" style="font-size: 1rem;"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('update/<int:pk>/', UpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
path('clone/<int:pk>/', CloneView.cloneRecord(), name='clone'),
...
]
```

and my `views.py` contains a clone view with a function to clone the record and open the `UpdateView` with the cloned record for editing:

```
class CloneView(LoginRequiredMixin):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = mymodel
    def cloneRecord(self,**kwargs):
        record = mymodel.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET['ID'])[0]
        record.id = None
        record.save()
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/update/', kwargs={'pk':record.id}))
```

At the moment I am receiving following error:

> TypeError: cloneRecord() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have seperate urls for both views, then you should write your code in `GET` method like this

```
class CloneView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'

    def get(self,**kwargs):
        record = mymodel.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET['ID'])[0]
        record.id = None
        record.save()
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/update/', kwargs={'pk':record.id}))
```

Your url should be like this

```
path('clone/<int:pk>/', CloneView.as_view(), name='clone'),
```

Remember that `as_view` is used to call a class based view. You cannot change according to function you are calling.

Comment: This ends up in following error: `AttributeError: type object 'CloneView' has no attribute 'as_view'.` Added generic UpdateView to class definition and then run into this error: `get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Sorry, you will have to inherit this view from `View`. I missed it earlier.

Comment: Inheriting from View did the first step. Needed to change the function a little, but now got it to work. Added the final class definition for reference above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant cloning an object. Biggest advantage is that you open your desired CreateView then it fills in the object from which you have got your id and then you can save it if you want. Don't forget to implement some unique constraint into your model to avoid duplicate records!
In this case you won't be in the situation where users are generating useless duplicate records, because it will only be saved when the user really saves it with the submit button in the AssemblyCloneView!

`urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('assembly/clone/<int:pk>/', AssemblyCloneView.as_view(), name='assembly_clone'),
```

`template.html:` (using a bootstrap button in my case)

```
<a class="btn btn-light btn-sm" href="{% url 'engineering:assembly_clone' record.id %}">Clone</a>
```

`views.py:`

```py
class AssemblyCloneView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Assembly

    """
    Get object desired from url with record.id and override the object context with it.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        print(context)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('engineering:assembly_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: best answer imho; the override of the get_success_url is not even mandatory in that case 
the idea of using create view is in fact clever

Answer (score 0):

remove parenthesis, CloneView.cloneRecord()

```
path('clone/<int:pk>/', CloneView.cloneRecord, name='clone'),
```